# User press image button to open a URL without a new window appearing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

How do I make it so that the user presses the image button and a URL link gets pressed without opening a new window?

```
private class HandleClick implements View.OnClickListener {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {




        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks1);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=1");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if (arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton1){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks2);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=2");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton2){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks3);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=3");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if (arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton4){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks4);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=4");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
              startActivity(intent);

        }
```

I would like for the user to press an image button and the URL without opening a new window, 
-clarification: 
I don't want to show the user a webpage on what happens when he/she presses the URL link, only that it has been pressed.

Comment: if you call the URL via intent it will open browser (mean new tab),instead of this u can use web view to load URL inside the application

Comment: We need more clarification (maybe an example?) what do you want to achieve? It is not clear what is the desired effect.

Comment: @SebastianPakieła Updated the desired effect. The user should not be able to see the website URL, when the user presses the image button it should only load the URL.

Comment: So, basically you should not call this intent. You have to create new Fragment/Activity depending on what your app looks like and load image using library like Picasso/Glide/UIL whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you call the URL via intent it will open browser (mean new tab),instead of this u can use web view to load URL inside the application

in Xml layout:

```
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
```

in Activity:

```
   WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        browser .setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        browser .getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        browser .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser .setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        browser .loadUrl(url);

 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

this starts a new activity. If you do not want to start a new activity, but want the url to be shown in the current activity, you need to add a webview in the layout for the currect activity and open the url in  the webview instead of calling startActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open URI in external browser, you should use `WebView`

You can add `WebView` to your layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

And then in your activity:

```
private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), error.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Find your `WebView` by id and set address to open

```
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
webView.loadUrl(yourUrl);
```